# Android java tts.isLanguageAvailable() not working even after language is available

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I want to check if a specific language pack (Google Text-to-Speech) is available or not.

```
t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
               if(t1.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("bn_BD")) >= TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
               {
                // Set language
               }
            }
        });
```

but the problem is **t1.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("bn_BD"))** is always returing false even the language is available and also working this voice.

Answer (score 1):

You must construct the Locale object using *separate* strings for the language and country like this:

```
new Locale("bn", "BD")
```

see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#public-constructors). :)